# Как в цикле for корректно принимать типы строка или список?

Tags: python, строки, list

Есть цикл для обработки файлов:

```
for filename in filenames:
```

Файл может быть один или несколько.

Если на цикл подать 1 файл в виде строки, то получится: разбиение по символам:

```
f i l e . t x t
```

`list(filenames)` даёт разбиение `f i l e . t x t`

`[filenames]` строку превращает в список без разбиения `['file.txt']`

А вот список `[filenames]` превращает в список в списке `[['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']]`, что нарушает цикл.

Понятно, что можно один файл передавать в виде списка как `['file.txt']` и не париться.

Однако, для других подобных задач хочется понять, когда нельзя повлиять на ввод значений.

Какие есть способы переводить строку в список без посимвольного разбиения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(filenames, str):
    filenames = [filenames]

for filename in filenames:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, а использование условия в цикле насколько допустимо? Не считается это плохим стилем кода? ```for filename in [filenames] if isinstance(filenames, str) else filenames:```

Comment: @KatsubaMikhail Такое не очень удобно читать. Когда пишутся "однострочники" по приколу так можно делать, а в реальных задачах лучше рефакторить код в сторону лучшей читаемости, а это значит короткие строки и понятные действия.

Comment: @KatsubaMikhail, эту проверку нужно сделать __до__ цикла - такой код будет более понятным, по-моему  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не знаете сколько файлов будете обрабатывать, то можно использовать функцию с `*args` не известным кол-во аргументов.

```
def work(*args):
    for file in args:
        print(file)


work('first.txt') # first.txt
work('first.txt', 'second.txt') # first.txt
                                # second.txt
```